# Angular2: Escape character in component's input

Tags: angular

I have the following code :

```
<my-comp [title]="Foo's component"></my-comp>
```

I have tried many things (`''`, `\'`, `\\'`, `\''`, ...)to escape the `'` in, but I didn't manage to do it.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that title is a component property, hence it expects a variable or a string. I assume the correct syntax would be:

```
<my-comp [title]="'Foo\'s component'"></my-comp>
```

Adding a single quote before and after

Comment: Want to add that taking the [ ] brackets off the title attribute is also valid.  Value will then be taken as a string, and then escaping the single quote won't be necessary `<my-comp title="Foo's component"></my-comp>`.

Answer (score 1):

You're binding to the `title` property, which is probably of type string.
What you're actually doing is binding it to a javascript (well.. angular2) expression, which is `Foo's component` but that's not a valid expression.

What you should be doing is:

- Either set the component's `title` property without the binding syntax, simply `title="Foo's Component"`
- alternatively, bind it to a string like this: `[title]="'Foo\'s component'"`.